# List a sharepoint folder using python office365 containing more than 5000 files

Tags: python-3.x, exception, sharepoint-online, office365api

```
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.runtime.client_request_exception import ClientRequestException
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import io
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import io
import datetime
import pandas as pd
app_principal = {
        'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

sp_site = 'https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/TSM839/'
relative_url = "/sites/TSM839/Shared Documents"
client_credentials = ClientCredential(app_principal['client_id'], app_principal['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(sp_site).with_credentials(client_credentials)
libraryRoot = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path(relative_url)
ctx.load(libraryRoot)
ctx.execute_query()
files = libraryRoot.files
ctx.load(files)
ctx.execute_query()
len(files)
```

**use case : Fetch the names of all the files in SharePoint folder**

This program works perfectly when the number of files in the SharePoint folder is < 5000, when it is > 5000, getting below exception

[image]